# Vertical lines are being broken up (disrupted) by the horizontal booktabs lines

Tags: tables, rules, booktabs

My vertical lines are being broken up (disrupted) by horizontal `booktabs` lines.  How can I fix this?

It's well and good to say use `\hline` but I also need a `cmidrule` that spans only the second two columns which have no `\hline` equivalent to my knowledge.  Also `\hline` is ugly because it doesn't automatically leave any vertical space between the line and the preceding/following lines of text.

[image: Table]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\date{}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{booktabs} %for top, middle and bottomline
\usepackage{multirow} %multi column and row spanning
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}


    \begin{document}

    \begin{multicols}{2}

    \subsection*{Results}

 \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{} l | c | c @{}}
\toprule
Characteristic & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Result}\\
 \cmidrule{2-3}
 & Seaweed isolate & Coral isolate \\
\midrule
Cell shape & Rod & Rod\\
Gram stain & $-$ & $-$\\
Oxidase & $+$ & $-$\\
Catalase & $+$ & $-$\\
MSA & Growth & No growth\\
Anaerobic & Growth (weak) & No growth\\
Motility & & \\
Indole production & & \\
Hugh \& Leifsons & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}

    \blindtext

    {\noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}
    { | l | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash} X | >{\centering\arraybackslash} X | }
    Leave this column alone. & Left justify and adjust this column. &
    Centre and adjust this column. \\ 
    \end{tabularx}
    }

    \end{multicols}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: You do know about `\cline`, I guess? It can be used to form 'grid lines' using a tabular, but as you say is horrible.

Comment: BTW, please consider editing your answer down to a _minimal_ example: most of the packages you load are not needed.

Comment: (As you know about `booktabs`, I'm left wondering _why_ you want vertical lines. The `booktabs` manual is pretty clear on why they are not a good thing in formal tables.)

Comment: Is there no way to do this with booktab rules?  It does look awful with \cline and \hlines...  (No automatic padding between text and rules; it has a very cramped appearance.)

Comment: @ptrcao: Please read the `booktabs` manual on this. As you should not have vertical rules in formal tables, they are not supported by `booktabs`. (I suspect the implementation would also be awkward, to say the least.)

Comment: To reinforce @Joseph Wright, Simon Fear does say, pretty clearly, that vertical lines in tables are a typographic abomination. My guess would be that if you want vertical lines, then `booktabs` isn't for you.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I know it is discouraged; rest assured, I've read the manual and I know the comment by the package author you refer to.  The reason I'm using vertical rules is more because it is a publication convention.

Comment: I appreciate the advice and I know where it is coming from.  I try to avoid it where I can.  If anyone knows how to implement unbroken vertical lies with booktabs or otherwise to equivalent effect, I'd still be interested.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the `\extrarowheight` command from the `array` package to stretch all the rows. Otherwise you can define your own "strut" command to enlarge a single row. The code below is based on `array`'s strut box.  If you are using vertical lines, then us it on the sides also.

EDIT: There is also the [bigstrut](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bigstrut) package

I have also include an example how to do it properly with `booktabs`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
    %\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\usepackage{booktabs} %for top, middle and bottomline
\usepackage{bigstrut}
    \setlength\bigstrutjot{3pt}

\makeatletter
\newlength\mylena
\newlength\mylenb
\newcommand\mystrut[1][2]{%
    \setlength\mylena{#1\ht\@arstrutbox}%
    \setlength\mylenb{#1\dp\@arstrutbox}%
    \rule[\mylenb]{0pt}{\mylena}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent With mystrut\par
\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
\hline
    \mystrut   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Result}\\
\cline{2-3}
    \mystrut
    Characteristic    & Seaweed isolate & Coral isolate  \\
\hline
    \mystrut
    Cell shape        & Rod             & Rod\\
    Gram stain        & $-$             & $-$\\
    Oxidase           & $+$             & $-$\\
    Catalase          & $+$             & $-$\\
    MSA               & Growth          & No growth\\
    Anaerobic         & Growth (weak)   & No growth\\
    Motility          &                 & \\
    Indole production &                 & \\
    Hugh \& Leifsons  &                 & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\noindent With bigstrut\par
\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
\hline
    \bigstrut   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Result}\\
\cline{2-3}
    \bigstrut
    Characteristic    & Seaweed isolate & Coral isolate  \\
\hline
    \bigstrut[t]
    Cell shape        & Rod             & Rod\\
    Gram stain        & $-$             & $-$\\
    Oxidase           & $+$             & $-$\\
    Catalase          & $+$             & $-$\\
    MSA               & Growth          & No growth\\
    Anaerobic         & Growth (weak)   & No growth\\
    Motility          &                 & \\
    Indole production &                 & \\
    \bigstrut[b]
    Hugh \& Leifsons  &                 & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\noindent With booktabs\par
\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{@{}lcc@{}}
\toprule
                      & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Result}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-3}
     Characteristic   & Seaweed isolate & Coral isolate \\
\cmidrule( r){1-1}
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}
\cmidrule(l ){3-3}
    Cell shape        & Rod             & Rod\\
    Gram stain        & $-$             & $-$\\
    Oxidase           & $+$             & $-$\\
    Catalase          & $+$             & $-$\\
    MSA               & Growth          & No growth\\
    Anaerobic         & Growth (weak)   & No growth\\
    Motility          &                 & \\
    Indole production &                 & \\
    Hugh \& Leifsons  &                 & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

Comment: Comprehensive and to the point.  Thanks Danie.  :)

Answer (score 3):

If you actually want to use vertical rules with the rules of `booktabs` (which is not at all in the spirit of `booktabs`), you can use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{@{} l | c | c @{}}
\toprule
Characteristic & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Result}\\
 \cmidrule{2-3}
 & Seaweed isolate & Coral isolate \\
\midrule
Cell shape & Rod & Rod\\
Gram stain & $-$ & $-$\\
Oxidase & $+$ & $-$\\
Catalase & $+$ & $-$\\
MSA & Growth & No growth\\
Anaerobic & Growth (weak) & No growth\\
Motility & & \\
Indole production & & \\
Hugh \& Leifsons & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution with `booktabs` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package: booktabs and vertical rules work well together.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} 

\begin{document}

\begin{booktabs}{@{} l | c | c @{}}
\toprule
Characteristic & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Result \\
\cmidrule{2-3}
 & Seaweed isolate & Coral isolate \\
\midrule
Cell shape & Rod & Rod\\
Gram stain & $-$ & $-$\\
Oxidase & $+$ & $-$\\
Catalase & $+$ & $-$\\
MSA & Growth & No growth\\
Anaerobic & Growth (weak) & No growth\\
Motility & & \\
Indole production & & \\
Hugh \& Leifsons & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{booktabs}

\end{document}
```

[image]