# Specific horizontal space with vertical lines

Tags: tables, booktabs

I would like to add one specific located horizontal space in a table (not after all rows like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18092/vertical-lines-are-being-broken-up-disrupted-by-the-horizontal-booktabs-lines)). For instance, `\addlinespace` works perfectly well but not when vertical lines are added.

```
 \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|} 
    \hline
        blabla & blabla\\ \hline
\addlinespace
        blabla & blabla\\ \hline
        blabla & blabla\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Please let me know if there is a more efficient and parsimonious solution.

Comment: `\addlinespace` is from `booktabs`, a package which does not really support vertical lines or better: `booktabs` is a package that is designed to provide nicely looking tables -- which is most times not the case for tables with vertical lines

Comment: you mean vertical space, not horizontal I think.

Comment: use `\\[5cm]` to add extra space without breaking the lines.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle but `\\[5cm]` works only before `\hline`. I would prefer to have the horizontal space after `\hline`, which is the purpose of `\addlinespace`

Comment: Really it is more normal to call that vertical space (it pushes the following line down, like `\vspace`) horiziontal space pushes the following things to the right, like `\hspace`  the standard mechanism to do that without breaking likes is to replace `\addlinespace` by `\rule{0pt}{5xm}`

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle for the rule option. Yes, in the future I will call it vertical space!

Comment: Thanks @ChristianHupfer. For a while I thought that the use of vertical lines was a matter of taste to avoid any ambiguity when using `\multicolumn`. But I tried the package `booktabs` more seriously and it designs nice looking tables with no ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase the space under the `\hrule` by increasing the height of the next row for example replacing `\addlinespace`  by `\rule{0pt}{40pt}` for some suitable height 40pt.