# Columns in tables produced using booktabs

Tags: tables, booktabs

I'm trying to make a table using the `booktabs` package. Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,amssymb]{amsart}
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}\hspace*{-1cm}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[h]{ccccccc}
\toprule
$\circ$ & $1$ & $r$ & $r^2$ & $s$ & $sr$ & $sr^2$  \\
\midrule
$1$ & $1$ & $r$ & $r^2$ & $s$ & $sr$ & $sr^2$  \\
\midrule
$r$ & $r$ & $r^2$ & $1$ & $sr^2$ & $s$ & $sr$  \\
\midrule
$r^2$ & $r^2$ & $1$ & $r$ & $sr$ & $sr^2$ & $sr$  \\
\midrule
$s$ & $s$ & $sr$ & $sr^2$ & $1$ & $r$ & $r^2$  \\
\midrule
$sr$ & $sr$ & $sr^2$ & $s$ & $r^2$ & $1$ & $r$  \\
\midrule
$sr^2$ & $sr^2$ & $s$ & $sr$ & $r$ & $r^2$ & $1$  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Group Table for $D_6$}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Here's the output:

[image]

I would like to add vertical columns, but the package produces vertical lines that are broken by each row.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It's part of the unabashed design philosophy of the `booktabs` package *never* to use vertical rules. :-)

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18092/134144 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88929/134144

Comment: If you  read the booktabs manual you will see that making vertical lines unusable is a design aim. also `}[h]` `tabular` does not have an `h` option, unfortunately latex doesn't flag that error, it just ignores the `h` (the only  allowed values are `t` `c` or `b`)

Comment: Off-topic: What's the purpose of the `\hspace*{-1cm}` directive? It causes the `tabular` environment to be shifted 1cm to the left, causing a noticeably asymmetric placement of the caption.

Comment: What do you mean with ‘adding vertical columns’?

Answer (score 2):

A hallmark of well-designed tables is that they (a) hardly ever use vertical lines and (b) use few, but well-spaced, horizontal lines. Whitespace can be every bit as effective as a visual separator.

Applied to your table, I would like to suggest that you not use *any* `\midrule` directives; instead, simply increase the value of `\arraystretch` a bit. (I use a value of `1.25` in the example below.)

Separately, since every single cell in the 7*7 table contains a math formula, you may want to use an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment. This lets you avoid having to type `2*7*7=98` [!] separate `$` symbols -- two per cell...

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,amssymb]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools,booktabs,caption,fullpage}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
$\begin{array}{@{} *{7}{c} @{}}
\toprule
\circ& 1   & r   & r^2 & s   & sr  & sr^2 \\
1    & 1   & r   & r^2 & s   & sr  & sr^2 \\
r    & r   & r^2 & 1   & sr^2& s   & sr   \\
r^2  & r^2 & 1   & r   & sr  & sr^2& sr   \\
s    & s   & sr  & sr^2& 1   & r   & r^2  \\
sr   & sr  & sr^2& s   & r^2 & 1   & r    \\
sr^2 & sr^2& s   & sr  & r   & r^2 & 1    \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\caption{Group Table for $D_6$}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Cayley tables are not normal tables for data, so I suggest *not* using `booktabs` for them.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

% adjustments for this table
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{.3ex} % add to the height
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} % add some space between rows
\captionsetup{belowskip=2ex}

$\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
\circ & 1 & r & r^2 & s & sr & sr^2  \\
\hline
1 & 1 & r & r^2 & s & sr & sr^2  \\
r & r & r^2 & 1 & sr^2 & s & sr  \\
r^2 & r^2 & 1 & r & sr & sr^2 & sr  \\
s & s & sr & sr^2 & 1 & r & r^2  \\
sr & sr & sr^2 & s & r^2 & 1 & r  \\
sr^2 & sr^2 & s & sr & r & r^2 & 1  \\
\end{array}$

\caption{Group Table for $D_6$}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I only added the necessary packages; perhaps the `\captionsetup` command should go in the preamble, if you prefer table caption to be at the bottom.

The option `amssymb` to `\documentclass` doesn't make sense. Also, `amsmath` and `amsthm` are automatically loaded with `amsart`.

A couple of adjustments are made: some additional height for the cells and some more spacing between rows. Using `array` avoids the need for `$` commands.

[image]